# How to customize edwin editor on mac?

Tags: scheme, lisp, editor

I was following this tutorial: https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/gjs/6.945/dont-panic/ (section 3.4.2) to get the edwin editor setup on my mac where they use the following file: http://web.mit.edu/6.945/dont-panic/.edwin for customizing the editor. However, I am unable to proceed using the instructions they have provided.

I cannot find the .edwin file on my mac and the wget command does not work. I was wondering if there was a different way of doing this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you create this file on your machine, it will not exist.  This seems rather obvious.

Until you install a wget binary from somewhere, there is no wget binary on your mac, so of course the command "does not work".

Failing actually installing a copy of wget, use curl, which ships on the mac.

$ curl -o .edwin http://web.mit.edu/6.945/dont-panic/.edwin